# Need to pull commission rate from one array into the output

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm in a beginners Java class and am having trouble with getting this to work. I need to get my program to pull the commission rate from one array into the output. Everything else seems to be working but it won't calculate the commission and I'm not sure what I am missing. Any help would be wonderful!

```
    public class Annualwages extends salesperson
     {

       /** @param args the command line arguments     */

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        { //begins the main method

         salesperson sp = new salesperson();
         sp.saleInformation();


            System.out.println("You entered the following:");

            System.out.println();
              for (int index = 0; index < sp.salesP.length; index++) 
             {
                System.out.println("Sales Person " + (index + 1));
                System.out.println("   Name: "
                        + sp.salesP[index]);
                System.out.println("   Total Annual Sales: "
                        + sp.sales[index]);
                System.out.println("   Base Salary is: " + sp.SALARY);
                System.out.println("   Annual Commission is: "
                        + sp.comm[index]);
                System.out.println("   Total Annual Compensation is: "
                        + sp.totalWages );
                System.out.println();
            }



            } // ends main method

            } //ends annual wages class
```

---

```
    package annualwages;

    import java.util.Scanner;


    class salesperson { //begins salesperson class
         protected String name;
         protected String[] salesP; // To reference an array of sales people
         protected double[] sales; // references an array for sales achieved
         protected double[] comm; // references an array for commission rate
         protected int numSales; // Number of sales people & sales achieved
         protected final double COMMISSION=0.15; //Sets a fixed variable for      commission earned
         protected final double SALARY=50000; //Sets a fixed variable for Salary earned
         protected final double SALESTARGET=120000; //Sets a fixed variable for the sales target
         protected double totalSales, totalWages, actualCommission, accelFactor=1.25;

         public void saleInformation()
        { //begins saleInformation method
         // Create a Scanner object to read input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Get number of sales people
            System.out.print("How many sales people do you want to compare? ");
            numSales = keyboard.nextInt();

            // Creates an array to hold number of sales people.
            salesP = new String [numSales];

            //Gets the names of the sales people.
            for (int index = 0; index < salesP.length; index++)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter name of sales person "
                          + (index + 1) + ": ");
                salesP[index] = keyboard.next();
                        }

           //creates an array to hold amoount in sales achieved
            sales = new double[numSales];

            // gets the amount in sales that each sales person has achieved  annually
            for (int index = 0; index < sales.length; index++)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter amount in sales achieved per person annually "
                            + (index + 1) + ": ");
                sales[index] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            }

            // creates an array to hold the commission rate
            comm = new double [numSales];

         //Sales incentive begins at a minimum at $96,000 in sales.
         //if less than, then no commission is earned
            for (int index = 0; index < comm.length; index ++)       
            {
                        if (sales.length <= 96000)
                { 
                actualCommission=0;
                }

                    // Sales incentive with $96,000 or more earns 15% commission
                    else if ((sales.length > 96000) && (sales.length < SALESTARGET ))
                        {
                        actualCommission=COMMISSION;
                        }

                    //Sales incentive increases if the sales person earns more than $120,000
                    //in sales with the acceleration factor of 1.25
                    else
                        {
                        actualCommission=COMMISSION*accelFactor;
                        }
            }
                     //Calculates total sales by multiplying sales and commission
                     totalSales = sales.length* comm.length;

                    //Calculates total wages by adding salary to total sales
                     totalWages = SALARY + totalSales;


        } //ends saleInformation method

    } //ends salesperson class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors.

- You're not assigning any value to `comm[index]` when you calculate the commission.  Instead of using the `actualCommission` variable (which you never actually display), just assign directly to `comm[index]`.
- The variable `sales.length` is unlikely ever to be 96000 or more, since it's the number of sales you're putting in.  So the first `if` condition is going to return `true` every time, and you'll end up setting the commission to zero.  Perhaps you meant to write `if (sales[index] <= 96000)` instead.  Similarly for the other comparisons involving `sales.length`.

Comment: I tried what you said and it's still not pulling the commission rate.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that helped with the commission. Now I just need to see if i can figure out why the annual compensation isn't working. It's not pulling the actual wages correctly.

Comment: Yes, I see that.  If I can offer some advice, I think now would be a good time to learn to use a debugger.  It will show you immediately what's going on here.  Learning to use a debugger early in your programming career will save you an unbelievable amount of time.

Comment: Is there a debugger you recommend? I have to use netbeans IDE to write the program, per the class instructions.

Comment: The debugger that's built into Netbeans will do just fine.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.